# Image not loaded on template

Tags: django, amazon-s3

Image not loaded on template,
This is my view

```
ob = article.objects.raw("select * from blogapp_article as a inner join blogapp_useradd as b on a.userid=b.uname ORDER BY a.id DESC")
```

'data1': ob

On template

```
{% for item in data1 %}
        <img src="{{ item.upic.url }}" style="width: 60px">
        {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class useradd(models.Model):
    uname = models.EmailField(max_length=20)
    pswd = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    upic=models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='India')
    contact = models.IntegerField(default='0123456789')

class article(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='content')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='title')
    d_and_t = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='local_01')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must configuring static files management.It is very clear.
Firstly you must define your static file path and static url in your `settings.py` file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/', # your static files path here
]
```

After that, you must add static url definition to your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Finally, you must use `{% static 'file_name'%}` template tag in your templates like that:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

Please look up for detail [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: These all are satisfied in my settings file and template. But problem is still there. I'm using aws s3 bucket for storing files

Comment: Ok, I got it, after loaded page could you inspect element and get src attribute url from img tag. When you open this on browser, is image loading? If it is not loading, your src value is wrong.

Comment: Ya, img src does't have any value after loading  page and  image is loaded when i avoid the inner join query. But i want the image from the inner query, What can i do ?

Comment: I did not pay attention your query. Could you edited post and share your models?

Comment: Okay, now model is here.